# jquery ajax posting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Hey all, I cannot seem to get a simple ajax working between a php page and jquery. I have followed a few tutorials. but having trouble actually understanding what is actually going on.

Javascript (JQuery)

```
$(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        askajax;
    });

    function askajax(){
        $.post("ask.php",{ question: "canuseeme" } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='yes')
          {
            alert("answer is yes");
          }
          else
          {
            alert("answer is no");
          }
       });
    }
});
```

The PHP:

```
if($_POST['question']){
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Any ideas guys?

EDIT: THANKS TO @Jacob

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){

        alert("doing ajax"); // THIS SHOWS
        $.post("ask.php",{ question: "canuseeme" }, function(data)
        {
          if(data=='yes')
          {
            alert("answer is yes"); // THIS DOESNT
          }
          else
          {
            alert("answer is no"); // THIS DOESNT
          }
       });
    });
```

Comment: It appears that ask.php is not responding to the request. Is ask.php in the same folder as the JavaScript? You may want to try the FireBug plugin for Firefox to see what response the browser is getting from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll work:

```
$('#trigger').click(askajax);
```

Or this:

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
   askajax();
});
```

But I prefer to do it this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        $.post("ask.php",{ question: "canuseeme" } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='yes')
          {
            alert("answer is yes");
          }
          else
          {
            alert("answer is no");
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Reason being that you don't ever use the `askajax` function again, and it will only be defined in the `ready` function's scope, so why even bother with a standalone function definition? Just use an anonymous function and be done with it. :)

Comment: Hey Jacob. Thanks I fully agree with your methodology. Still not working. Is this code working on your end?

Comment: @claw Did you verify that the Ajax request fires?

Comment: ok. how should i verify jacob? sorry im a js noob - please see op post edit

Comment: @claw Use Firebug in Firefox to debug this. You can use the built-in tools that it has.

Comment: @jacob relkin - checked the js console. it was looking for ask.php in the root of my webserver. now fixed with new path.

Comment: @Jacob - thanks for making me checked the debugger. forgot :)

Answer (score 1):

On line 3, change `askajax;` to `askajax();`